# Get Birthdates ( if shared publicly ) from User profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

User can make Birth date private/public. For example a profile https://www.facebook.com/jas.lu2012/about even though she is not my friend I can see birthdate; but how do I get it via API ?

I want to get birthdate ONLY if it is public.. Why do we need additional permissions when it is a public data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't**. Even if some user has made his/her birthday public, API has its own limitations.

Unless the user has used your app and has given it **user_birthday** permission, you can not fetch his/her birth date.

Comment: I understand.. And seeing that you are top guy on Facebook-api on stackoverflow.. Most probably you are correct. Is there any possible workaround ( other than scrapping )

Comment: This Top guy is in fact right! Ideally, it should work according to the Facebook's definition of [Public Information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/). You cant do that unless your app has been given that permission.

Comment: @Deepak Other than scrapping- I'm afraid not.

Comment: Ok let me wait for some more time if someone else comes with a solution. If not, then I will mark this as correct answer.